# Selenium Testing - Text addition via pop up window is not getting saved

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a website using selenium web driver.
On the website, there is a popup form for creating a gate name with a text field to enter the text. Using selenium I tried to do, the pop up came but the given text was not getting saved. To pop up it's working correctly. Need guides to complete the action.

[image]

Methods I used are given below:

```
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("New Gate");
alert.accept();
System.out.println(alert.getText());
```

1. Elements are identified by the Xpath element locator.
2. I also gave text along with URL, another method that I got from the stack.

Comment: How are you trying to fetch the id for the text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its an alert then right way handle as per your requirement steps should be

1. switch to and alert
2. enter text
3. get entered text
4. accept

   ```
   Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
   alert.sendKeys("New Gate");
   System.out.println(alert.getText());
   alert.accept();`
   ```

If its a model popup then try to locate popup element and directly used send keys

sample code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.your_popup_locator));
driver.findElement(By.you_textbox_locator).sendKeys("expected text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to pop-up first. Then you can access elements in the pop-up.

```
 // save your main window handle
    String MainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();

    // Get all window handle    
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

Now, for each childHandle in handles,

```
driver.switchTo().window(childHandle );
// check if your textField present. 
// If found, do your actions and break;
//  else switch to next window
```

At last, switch to main window again.

```
 driver.switchTo().window(MainWindow);
```

Comment: We tried this..I've edited the question. Please see that too. Thanks

Comment: Thats a pop-up, right? switchToAlert wont work. Editing my answer.